# getting "Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to null" when running the command

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am getting `"Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to null"` when running the following command

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.bat --zookeeper 192.168.99.101:2181 --describe --group console-consumer-62252
```

Googled it but couldn't find any solution

Comment: I'm also experiencing the same exception. This command returned data a few minutes ago but started throwing this error when another server was added to the consumer group.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's still relevant, but the new Kafka using bootstrap-server instead of zookeeper, try this one:

```
./kafka-consumer-groups.sh --bootstrap-server 192.168.99.101:9092 --describe --group console-consumer-62252
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use list of bootstrap and see if --new-consumer work

```
sh kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server broker1host:port1,broker2host:port2...  --new-consumer --describe --group console-consumer-62252
```

or without --new-consumer if you are using kafka 2.8.0+

```
sh kafka-consumer-groups --bootstrap-server broker1host:port1,broker2host:port2...   --describe --group console-consumer-62252
```

Answer (score 0):

FWIW since this was the first result when I googled `Error: Executing consumer group command failed due to null`, I thought I'd record that plain old PEBCAK can also cause this error. I got it and puzzled over it for a few minutes before realising I was trying to reset offsets for a consumer group on a topic, and had a typo in the topic name...